# VBA Vlookup to Changing Workbook Name

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to a vlookup in vba between 2 workbooks. The workbook I'm looking up information from will have a different name every day. How do I write the vlookup to reference the current active workbook?

In my other code, I've being using Workbooks(2) as my reference but it doesn't seem to work in the vlookup.

Comment: Grab the name first? but may be better to architect it by grabbing the data you need via a variable from the second book instead.

Comment: Create a variable for the worksheet name, then update that variable.  Then just write the `vlookup` formula, and make sure to explicitly state which sheet which data is on.

Comment: Let's see the code, you are using

Comment: This is what I have tried:
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],[' & workbooks(2) & ']Pivot Tables'!C4:C5,2,FALSE),0)"

Comment: Try `"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],[" & Workbooks(2).Name & "]Pivot Tables'!C4:C5,2,FALSE),0)"`

Comment: This is what I typed and it gave me a syntax error

 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],[" & workbooks(2).Name & "]Pivot Tables'!C4:C5,2,FALSE),0)"

Comment: missed something `"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'[" & Workbooks(2).Name & "]Pivot Tables'!C4:C5,2,FALSE),0)"`  Also make sure that Workbooks(2) is the actual work book you want.

Comment: What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve? We might have a simpler solution than this.